# Why doesn't changing the "bottom" value of the div to "0" work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

Why doesn't changing the "bottom" value of the div to "0" work?

I have `top:0` in the css and replace it by `bottom:0` in the javascript.
(If I just change the "top" value then it does work...) -
Here is the code:

```js
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.top = "";
    document.getElementById("main").style.bottom = "0";
  };
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#all {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set top to "auto", to eliminate any previous specifications

```
<script>
(function() {
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.top = "auto";
        document.getElementById("main").style.bottom = "0";
    }
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `top` property is still zero - *unset* it using `top: unset` at the same time - see demo below:

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.top = "unset"; /* changed */
    document.getElementById("main").style.bottom = "0";
  }
}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#all {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant part from [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height):

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> `'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block`
>
> If all three of 'top', 'height', and 'bottom' are auto, set 'top' to the static position and apply rule number three below.
>
> If none of the three are 'auto': If both 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values. If one of 'margin-top' or 'margin-bottom' is 'auto', solve the equation for that value. If the values are over-constrained, **ignore the value for 'bottom' and solve for that value.**

So basically, if you set all the values (`top`, `bottom`, `height`) the browser will decide to ignore the bottom one.

You need to make the top value `auto`

```js
document.getElementById("main").style.top = "auto";
document.getElementById("main").style.bottom = "0";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#all {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

> 'top' is 'auto', 'height' and 'bottom' are not 'auto', then set 'auto' values for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' to 0, and solve for 'top'

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("main").style.top = "initial";
document.getElementById("main").style.bottom = "0";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#all {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```